# Hiding menu items in Fragment and showing them again on navback after `setHasOptionsMenu` deprecation with new menu provider API

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

A month or so ago, the Android team deprecated `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected`, as well as `setHasOptionsItemMenu`. This unfortunately broke all of my code.

My app has a lot of fragments, and when the user navigates to them, I always made sure that the menu items would disappear and reappear on navigating back, with the following code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
}
```

```
override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
    menu.clear()
}
```

This code worked well and was really simple. Now that the Android team has deprecated (why?) `setHasOptionsMenu`, I cannot recreate this code.

I understand the new syntax for inflating menu items and handling menu item click events, although I cannot figure out -- for the life of me -- how to hide the menu in a fragment and then show it again on navigation back using the new menu provider API.

Here's what I've tried:

*Navigating to the fragment:*

```
if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount == 0) {
            supportFragmentManager.commit {
                replace(R.id.activityMain_primaryFragmentHost, NewProjectFragment.newInstance(mainSpotlight != null))
                addToBackStack(null)
            }
        }
```

*`getRootMenuProvider` function in `ActivityFragment` interface:*

```
interface ActivityFragment {
    val title: String

    companion object {
        fun getRootMenuProvider() = object : MenuProvider {
            override fun onPrepareMenu(menu: Menu) {
                for (_menuItem in menu.children) {
                    _menuItem.isVisible = false
                }
            }

            override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
            }

            override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Using the `getRootMenuProvider` function:*

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()
        menuHost.addMenuProvider(ActivityFragment.getRootMenuProvider())
    }
```

*`MainActivity` (trying to restore the menu items to their previous state):*

```
    override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        for (_menu in menu.children) {
            _menu.isVisible = true
        }

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.activityMain_bottomNavigationView)?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        invalidateOptionsMenu()
    }
```

This hides the items in the fragment, but the items still remain hidden after navigating back until the user reloads the activity by rotating their screen, or doing something similar.

How to hide the menu items in a fragment and reappear them on navigation back *with the new menu provider API*?

Comment: What are you using to navigate between fragments? Please include that code. You also state that you "understand the new syntax for inflating menu items and handling menu item click events", but you haven't included *that* code either. Please include that as well.

Comment: Your `MenuProvider` is not actually creating any menu items. Where do you do that?

Comment: I don't want it to create any menu items in the fragment, just clear them. I create the primary menu items in `MainActivity` but I have not included that code as it is not relevant to the question.

Comment: I'm confused. If you want the visibility of menu items to be conditional based on whether a fragment is visible, then why aren't those menu items owned by that fragment?

Comment: @ianhanniballake  don't know what to tell you, I am confused by all of this.

Comment: So let me see if I get this correct. When you are on Fragment A, you want certain menu items to appear. When you go to Fragment B, you want all of the menu items that should be visible on Fragment A to disappear (and any menu items that should be visible with Fragment B to appear). Correct?

Comment: Yes, and that when you go back, Fragment A's menu items reappear again. (Fragment A is just `MainActivity`.)

Comment: What does "Fragment A is just MainActivity" mean? Your `replace` operation can only replace another Fragment, taking the original fragment's spot in your activity's layout. It sounds like your activity is not set up that way, but you haven't included any code about your activity.

Comment: Oh yeah 'replace' just replaces the fragment host (`R.id.activityMain_primaryFragmentHost`) in `MainActivity` with the fragment, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Short term**

The reason everything 'broke' is because you are assuming that `menu.clear()` and the dispatch of fragment menu calls happen after your activity has added its own menu items. Fragments now go through the dispatch of menu calls when your activity calls `super.onCreateOptionsMenu()` or `super.onPrepareOptionsMenu()` so often you can 'fix' your problem by making that the **last** thing your override calls, rather than the first.

**Long term**

In fact, you are doing a lot wrong: the global menu controlled by your Activity is a shared resource and no individual fragment should ever, ever be manually clearing the entire menu. This breaks activity menu items, child fragment menu items, as well as other fragment's menu items. Only the component that inflated certain menu items should ever be touching those specific menu items.

So to fix your problem, you should follow the [Activity 1.4.0-alpha01 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.4.0-alpha01) (the release that added the `MenuHost` and `MenuProvider` integration into the Activity layer:

> AndroidX `ComponentActivity` [and its subclasses of `FragmentActivity` and `AppCompatActivity`] now implements the `MenuHost` interface. This allows any component to add menu items to the `ActionBar` by adding a `MenuProvider` instance to the activity. **Each `MenuProvider` can optionally be added with a Lifecycle that will automatically control the visibility of those menu items based on the `Lifecycle` state and handle the removal of the `MenuProvider` when the `Lifecycle` is destroyed.**

They go onto show an example of its usage in a Fragment:

> ```
> /**
>   * Using the addMenuProvider() API in a Fragment
>   **/
> ExampleFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_example) {
>
>   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
>     // The usage of an interface lets you inject your own implementation
>     val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()
>   
>     // Add menu items without using the Fragment Menu APIs
>     // Note how we can tie the MenuProvider to the viewLifecycleOwner
>     // and an optional Lifecycle.State (here, RESUMED) to indicate when
>     // the menu should be visible
>     menuHost.addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider {
>       override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
>         // Add menu items here
>         menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.example_menu, menu)
>       }
>
>       override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
>         // Handle the menu selection
>         return true
>       }
>     }, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
>   }
> ```

This shows off three things in particular:

1. A single `MenuProvider` should only be touching its Menu Items. You should never, ever, ever be "clearing all menu items" or anything that affects another component's menu items.
2. By calling `addMenuProvider` with a Lifecycle (in this case, the Fragment view's Lifecycle - i.e., the one that only exists when the Fragment's view is on screen), then you **automatically** hide the menu items when your Fragment's view is destroyed (when your `replace` call happens) and **automatically** reshown when your fragment's view re-appears (i.e., when the back stack is popped).
3. That **the fragment itself** that is controlling the `Lifecycle` and visibility of the menu items should be the one creating and handling its own menu items. Your activity (which can add its own `MenuProvider` as seen in the other example) should only be adding menu items that exist for the entire Lifecycle of the activity (items that are visible on **all** fragments).

Comment: thanks for this explanation. this is such a great improvement.

Comment: @ianhannibalIake've been trying to work with this. I had a couple of fragments that didn't have menu items.

Comment: thank you for the explaination but how will I hide the previous menus?

Comment: @NoumanCh - if the previous fragment is no longer started, then those menu items will automatically be hidden.

Comment: @ianhannibalIake thanks for answer. but what kind of state i should use, when i'm use "add" func with fragment transaction? onPause not calling in this case.

Answer (score 2):

On a Single activity application, for hiding or showing menu in specific fragments where most fragments can follow same set of menus and very few fragments need to show or hide menus, add Menus using MenuProvider in the activity and show/hide using onPrepareMenu.

Eg:

```
    val menuProvider = object : MenuProvider {
            override fun onPrepareMenu(menu: Menu) {
               
                // Handle for example visibility of menu items
                val navHostFragment =
                    supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
                val profileMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.profile_page_fragment)
                profileMenu.isVisible =
                    navHostFragment?.childFragmentManager?.fragments?.get(0) !is MyProfileFragment

            }

            override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
                menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
            }

            override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
                // Validate and handle the selected menu item
               
               
                }
                return true
            }
        }
        addMenuProvider(menuProvider)
}
```

Comment: I have called the `menu.clear()` method inside `onPrepareMenu(menu: Menu)` to hide the menu.

Answer (score 0):

I have a number of fragments that don't require menu. Therefore I was clearing the menu. There now appears to be no way to satisfy that requirement.

Comment: Look at my answer, hopefully that will fix your issue.