# Duplicating menu items via different Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

After OnCreateOptionsMenu() marked as deprecated, I've managed to use new API from release notes https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.4.0-alpha01
In my app user can switch Fragments via bottomNavigation.
As I understand docs, in each Fragment I've implemented MenuProvider(with or without Lifecycle, doesn't matter for result). But now in each Fragment user have all items from all menuInflaters.
There is the code of implementation

FRAGMENT A

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        SetMainParams();
        fragment = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_A, container, false );

        addMenu();

        return fragment;
    }

    private void addMenu()
    {
        MenuProvider menuProvider = new MenuProvider()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCreateMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater menuInflater)
            {
                menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment_A, menu);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem)
            {
                if( menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.filters_prev )
                    filtersPrevious();
                else if( menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.filters )
                    showFilters();
                else
                    filtersNext();

                return false;
            }
        };

        requireActivity().addMenuProvider(menuProvider, getViewLifecycleOwner(), Lifecycle.State.RESUMED);
    }
```

FRAGMENT B

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        SetMainParams();
        binding = FragmentBBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        fragment = binding.getRoot();
        init();

        addMenu();

        return fragment;
    }

    private void addMenu()
    {
        MenuProvider menuProvider = new MenuProvider()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCreateMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater menuInflater)
            {
                menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment_B, menu);
                filtersMenu = menu.getItem(0);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem)
            {
                if( menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.filters )
                    loadFilters();

                return false;
            }
        };

        requireActivity().addMenuProvider(menuProvider, getViewLifecycleOwner(), Lifecycle.State.RESUMED);
    }
```

Switching from bottomNavigation

```
binding.bottomNav.setOnItemSelectedListener(item ->
        {
            int itemId = item.getItemId();

            if( itemId == R.id.A )
            {
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(active_fragment).show(A_fragment).commit();
                active_fragment = A_fragment;
                setWithElevation(false);
            }
            else if( itemId == R.id.B )
            {
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(active_fragment).show(B_fragment).commit();
                active_fragment = B_fragment;
                setWithElevation(true);
            }

            active_fragment.startFragment();
            active_fragment.setTitle();
            return true;
        });

        fm.beginTransaction().add( R.id.fl_content, A_fragment, "A_fragment" ).hide(A_fragment).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add( R.id.fl_content, B_fragment, "B_fragment" ).hide(B_fragment).commit();
```

Is there any ideas, why new API works like this, or maybe i've made a mistake. Thanks a lot for help :)

Comment: How do you swap between fragments vis your bottom nav?

Comment: Inside activity using BottomNavigationView
binding.bottomNav.setOnItemSelectedListener and then FragmentManager.beginTransaction

Comment: Please include your code. There's many, many things a FragmentTransaction can do.

Comment: My bad, sry) Edited my question with additional code

Comment: You've added all fragments at the same time, thus forcing all of their views to be created and kept in memory the entire time (as per [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions#views), hide and show do nothing to the fragment's lifecycle). Was that your intent when using that bottom nav code?

Comment: We develop this app in team, and I'm still too busy to do it normally)But I think, there is nothing bad here, cause old method works fine

Answer (score 3):

I also experienced this problem today.  So not sure if you have intellisense, but look at some of the `Menu` interface methods.  I used the [hasVisibleItems()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu#hasVisibleItems()) method in Kotlin to only inflate the menu if it does not exist.  Java also has the method; your snippet augmented with conditional:

```
MenuProvider menuProvider = new MenuProvider()
    {
         @Override
         public void onCreateMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater menuInflater)
         {
             if (!menu.hasVisibleItem()) {  // only inflate if no items
                 menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment_A, menu);
             }
         }        
//...
```

`Menu` also has a bunch of other methods that may assist for specific items.
Also another good idea would be to use the [MenuHost](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/MenuHost) interface to keep track of your `MenuProvider`.  I believe in Java; inside your Fragments; it would be along the lines of:

```
activityFragment = this.requireActivity();
Menuhost menuHost = (MenuHost) activityFragment;
menuHost.addMenuProvider(
    menuProvider,
    this.getViewLifecycleOwner(),
   State.RESUMED
);
```

Menu providers can then be invalidated ect.

Comment: Thank you for feedback and solution, but all my items in menu are visible. And they implemented each time i'll creating fragment. This doesn't work in my situation, but, again, thank you :)

Comment: @VsevolodCheverda To build on xcesco's answer, which is similar to what I use elsewhere: after hiding all items in your menu with `menu.clear()`; show all with my snippet above; then hide the ones you do not need with `menu.findItem(R.id.A)?.isVisible = false`

Comment: @Hmerman6006: This is what I do to prevent duplicate menu items: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76763866/android-studio-menuprovider-in-mainactivity-and-also-in-fragments/76766449#76766449

Answer (score 0):

I've a similar problem. In my application, I'm using fragments and navigation. The problem I found is that during navigation, the fragment never call the `onPause` event. So all my fragment implements this code in `onViewCreated` method:

```kotlin
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...

        val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()
        menuHost.addMenuProvider(HomeMenuProvider(R.id.nav_main, findNavController(), this, authViewModel, homeViewModel), viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
    }
```

The `HomeMenuProvider` is so defined:

```kotlin
class HomeMenuProvider(private val currentNavId: Int) : MenuProvider {
    override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        if ((navController.currentDestination?.id ?: -1L) == currentNavId) {
            menu.clear()
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        } 
    }

    override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (menuItem.itemId) {
            R.id.menu_action_login -> {
                ...
                true
            }
            else -> {
                false
            }

        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in my code, I add menu items only if the current navigation status is the one associated with the fragment. Otherwise, simply I do nothing.

To avoid menu persistence, before add items I clear the menu.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank's a lot for solution, but it seems little tricky. As i see docs, MenuHost and MenuProvider hold items sepparatly just in case not to clear the menu every time.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72864242/19668694
Here is explanation why, but let me try:) Maybe, this is good workaround)

Comment: Try it :), it works for me very well.