# Android Studio - MenuProvider in MainActivity and also in Fragments?

Tags: java, android, menu

I migrated from normal menus to MenuProvider so I added in MainActivity:

```
private void setMenuProvider() {
    addMenuProvider(new MenuProvider() {
        @Override
        public void onCreateMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater menuInflater) {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_action, menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareMenu(@NonNull Menu menu) {
            MenuItem itemIcon1 = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_icon1);
            Drawable resIcon1 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_32x32_icon1_green);
            if (statusForIcon1 == false)
                resIcon1.mutate().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            itemIcon1.setEnabled(statusForIcon1);
            itemIcon1.setIcon(resIcon1);

            MenuItem itemIcon2 = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_icon2);
            Drawable resIcon2 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_32x32_icon2_green);
            if (statusForIcon2 == false)
                resIcon2.mutate().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            itemIcon2.setEnabled(statusForIcon2);
            itemIcon2.setIcon(resIcon2);
            
            MenuItem itemIcon3 = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_icon3);
            Drawable resIcon3 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_32x32_icon3_green);
            if (statusForIcon3 == false)
                resIcon3.mutate().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            itemIcon3.setEnabled(statusForIcon3);
            itemIcon3.setIcon(resIcon3);

            MenuProvider.super.onPrepareMenu(menu);
        }
    });
}
```

and I have two fragment tabs where I added there too:

```
public void setFragmentOneMenuProvider( LifecycleOwner lcFragmentOne) {
    getActivity().addMenuProvider(new MenuProvider() {
        @Override
        public void onCreateMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater menuInflater) {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_action, menu);

            if (myClassObject == null)
                myClassObject = new ClassObject(getActivity(), getContext(), menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            return false;
        }
    }, lcFragmentOne , Lifecycle.State.RESUMED);
}
```

where I have also :

```
ublic View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View viewFragmentOne = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragmentone, container, true);
    
    setFragmentOneMenuProvider( getViewLifecycleOwner() );
    
    return viewFragmentOne;
}
```

but in this way with both :

```
View viewFragmentOne = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragmentone, container, true);
```

and

```
menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_action, menu);  // this one inside the MenuProvider code
```

I see like double menus ...does that mean if I add `MenuProvider` on MainActivity then in fragments then I shall just use:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

in the way to inform the system that my app bar fragment is participating in the population of the options menu or maybe I have just to modify the `MenuProvider` in my fragments?
In fact , if I click on fab button I added next to refresh status of icons where I call:

```
getActivity().invalidateMenu();
```

or

```
getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

supposing it should refresh the menu inflated by `MenuProvider` , it doesn't refresh anything....so I tried to comment the fragment's MenuProvider code keeping the `inflater.inflate` but it didn't changed at all about refreshing when it should refresh...maybe I missed something?...

Thanks in advance to all !! Cheers!!

Comment: Your fragment's `MenuProvider` implementation lacks `onPrepareMenu` callback implementation.

Comment: Hello @Kozmotronik , thanks for the answer, added right now the onPrepareMenu copying the same code from MainActivity and seems working but still I see like double menu due of `inflater.inflate` and `menuinflater` as you can see in the code in post..... I thought it could be passed directly `MainActivity` 's `MenuProvider` to fragment to avoid double code and avoid double inflate....

Comment: If you add a MenuProvider at the Activity level, those menu items will be available no matter what fragment you are on (and no matter if that fragment _also_ adds menu items via its own MenuProvider) - that's what adding at the activity level means. Is that what you are experiencing? What was your expectation?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot that shows the problem? Also another screenshot that shows your expectation would be great.

Comment: @ianhanniballake , in fact I don't need to add more menu items from fragment... just I need to reach menu items in activity.... does that mean then I just have to use `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` inside `onCreateView` 's event in fragments to reach MainActivity 's MenuProvider?.... or how I could reach Activity 's menu items from fragment?

Comment: The only thing that should be interacting with the activity's menu items is the activity. Your fragment shouldn't be involved at all. `setHasOptionsMenu` has no interaction at all with MenuProvider. Please take a step back and update your question with what you are trying to do to avoid an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@Luigino**

I've a similar or even the same requirements as you:

1. One main menu (defined in `R.menu.menu_main` and inflated in `MainActivity`) that contains all required menu entries used in all fragments.
2. Several fragments whereas I need to execute specific code in each fragment when the user clicks on a particular icon. For example, you're using a menu icon "Save" across all fragments but you want to save data shown in each fragment.

I've solved it as shown below, i.e. in each fragment in the according `onCreateMenu` I don't inflate the menu once again. That prevents the menu entries from duplicating.

See also https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.4.0-alpha01 for additional information.

Hope that helps!

**MainActivity:**

```
private void setupMenu() {
    MenuProvider menuProvider = new MenuProvider() {
        @Override
        public void onCreateMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater menuInflater) {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            int id = menuItem.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.menu_action_about) {
                /* show about dialog */
                return true;
            } else if (id == R.id.menu_action_settings) {
                /* show settings dialog */
                return true;
            } 
            return false;
        }
    };

    addMenuProvider(menuProvider);
}
```

**Fragment 1:**

```
private void setupMenu() {
    MenuProvider menuProvider = new MenuProvider() {
        @Override
        public void onCreateMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater menuInflater) {
            /* do not inflate the menu again */
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            int id = menuItem.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.menu_action_save) {
                /* execute specific code,
                   e.g. save data shown in fragment one */
                return true;
            } 
            return false;
        }
    };

    requireActivity().addMenuProvider(menuProvider, getViewLifecycleOwner(), Lifecycle.State.RESUMED);
}
```

Comment: Hello @Patrick  , in fact I tried also your solution but when I call `getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();` even if I have correctly settled icon selectors true/false as you can see in `onPrepareMenu` event in the post , if I call `getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();` right after I change menuItem icons state as expected, it doesn't redraw icons that are svg .xml selectors and I'm stuck on it...even if I debugged on menuItems and they are correctly evaluated as they are...

Comment: Hello again @Patrick , after some fighting and debugging I figured out to call redraw + `invalidateOptionsMenu()` from inside `onPrepareMenu` event so in this way it would redraw correctly the menu... thanks again!

Comment: Great to hear that it's working now @Luigino !